# How to find probability that the time a customer spends on the website has the indicated duration given the average and standard deviation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

ABC airline website manager does AB testing of assessing the website
engagement. He found that the average time penetrating the website from the beginning to checking out is $23.4$ minutes with standard deviation $10$ minutes. He would like to adapt the website for ease of usage. He finds the probability of following situations:
a) The probability of a customer spent at most $15$ minutes.
b) The probability of a customer spent at least $30$ minutes.
c) The probability of a customer spent between $10$ minutes to $30$ minutes.
d) The duration of time penetrating lower than $95\%$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

$ X \sim \mathcal{N}(24min, 4min).$

a)
$ Pr(\{X \leq 15 min.\})=Pr\left(\frac{X-15}{4}\leq \frac{15-24}{4}\right)= Pr(\{Z\leq -2,25\})= \phi(-2,25) = 1-\phi(2.25)\approx 0,012.$

b)
$ Pr(\{X \geq 30 min.\})=Pr\left(\frac{X-30}{4}\geq \frac{30-24}{4}\right)= 
Pr(\{Z\geq 1,5\})= 1- Pr(\{Z< 1,5\}) = 1-\phi(1,5)\approx 0,07.$

c)
$Pr(\{10 min.\leq X \leq 30 min\}) = Pr(\{\frac{10-24}{4}\leq Z \leq \frac{30-24}{4} =Pr(-3,5 \leq Z\leq 1,5\})=\phi(1,5)-\phi(-3,5)=\phi(1,5)+\phi(3,5)-1\approx 0,93.$

d)
$Pr(\{X \geq \Delta t \}) \leq 0,95$

$Pr(\{Z \geq \frac{\Delta t-24}{4}\}) \leq 0,95 $

$Pr(\left\{Z < \frac{\Delta t-24}{4}\right\}) \geq 0,05.$

$\phi\left\{\frac{\Delta t-24}{4}\right\}) \geq \phi(-1,64)$

$\frac{\Delta t-24}{4}\geq -1,64 $

$\Delta t \geq 17,4 min.$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please do not answer questions which do not meet [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).